# How to find the domain of $f\left(g\left(y\right)\right)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^3-27}$

Tags: calculus

Please help me find the domain of the following equation.

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x^3-27},\space \space \space g\left(y\right)=\frac{x+1}{x-1},\space \space \space find \space f。g\\
> \end{eqnarray}

The following is my calculation process.
\begin{eqnarray}
\\f\left(g\left(y\right)\right)&=&\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^3-27}\\
\\&=&\sqrt{\frac{\left(x+1\right)^3}{\left(x-1\right)^3}-3^3}\\
\\&=&\sqrt{\frac{\left(x+1\right)^3-\left[3\left(x-1\right)\right]^3}{\left(x-1\right)^3}}\\
\end{eqnarray}
Now, $x-1$ is not equal to 0 and found that when $x=1$, $f(x)$ does not exist.

\begin{eqnarray}
\\Using \space a^3-b^3&=&\left(a-b\right)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)\\
\\(4-2x)((x+1)^2+3(x+1)(x-1)+9(x-1)^2)&\ge&0\\
...
\\4-2x\ge/\le0 \space \space &and& \space \space 13x^2-16x+7\ge/\le0\\
...
\end{eqnarray}

Please give me some hints.

***Thank your for your attention***

---

The ans in book is (1, -4](exactly without mistyping)

Comment: What you say is the answer in your book is, first of all, wrongly expressed and, second, even if you meant $\;[-4,1)\;$ then it is wrong.

Comment: I also wonder whether it shoud be [−4, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don Antonio's answer is correct. If I may, I'd like to give a detailed explanation as to why this is so, just in case Don Antonio's answer is too difficult to follow for some who are still learning this stuff.

The domain of a function is the set of all allowed values you can put into the function, i.e. all allowed values of $x$. In this case, there are two parts of the function which may make a value of $x$ not allowed:

First, there is the fraction with denominator $x - 1$. Dividing by zero is not allowed, so this means $x = 1$ cannot be part of the domain.

Second, there is the square root. It is not allowed to put negative values in the square root (zero is okay), so whatever is under the square root needs to be larger than or equal to zero, so what is left to do is to figure out for which values of $x$ is

$\left(\frac{x+1}{x−1}\right)^3−27 \ge 0$

This is true for $\frac{x+1}{x−1} \ge 3$.

When solving an inequality, you should first check when the two sides are equal, ie solve $\frac{x+1}{x−1} = 3$. Multiplying by $x-1$ on both sides we get $x+1 = 3(x-1)$ which, as you may check is true if $x = 2$. Note that special care should be taken at $x = 1$ as well, since the fraction changes sign there.

The last step in solving the inequality is checking for which values of $x$ (smaller than 1, in between 1 and 2, larger than 2) the inequality $\frac{x+1}{x−1} \ge 3$ holds. This can be done by choosing values for $x$ in the respective intervals. If you do this, you'll see that $\frac{x+1}{x−1} \ge 3$ for $x \in (1, 2]$,

Hence, as Don Antonio said, the domain of the function is $(1, 2]$.

Comment: In the final step you state, can I multiply $(x-1)^2$ in both sides in order to ensure that the (x-1) is not a negative value and the sign will not change? However, when I do this, finally I will get $0\ge 2x^2-6x+6$. It is not easy to fractorize it. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function's defined, over the real numbers, iff

$$\frac{x+1}{x-1}\ge 3\iff \frac{-2x+4}{x-1}\ge0\iff\frac{x-2}{x-1}\le 0\iff$$

$$(x-1)(x-2)\le 0\;,\;\;x\neq 1\iff 1<x\le 2\implies \;\text{the solution's the interval}\;(1,2]$$